# append CSV file to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three different data files they are json, pkl and csv.

I am trying to combine them together before do data analysis.

Currently I am able to combine pkl and json file. But not sure how to do with CSV.

```
import json
import csv
import pickle
import operator

objects = []
with (open("data.pkl", "rb")) as openfile:
    objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
with(open('data.json','rb'))as openfile:
    objects.append(json.load(openfile))

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
objects.append(reader)
```

Not sure how to append the csv file and I need to sort the unique value after combing them.

Comment: Well, have you read the CSV module documentation and tried something? Are there any errors you'd like to point out when you do?

Comment: Note: you're appending single objects, not lists of data. If you print `len(objects)` here, it'll only be 2, not the sum of the lengths of the two lists (?) that you loaded

Comment: Yes, I try to append the reader method, but when I check it did not append the result.

Comment: Because you're never actually reading the lines, only creating the reader https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: What exactly should the format of the csv object in the `objects` list be? Python has no native "csv" type. Its `csv` module will let you convert one to **sequence**  of `tuple`s or `dict`s (and `namedtuple`s I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally want the text appended to a list, you don't need the CSV module. This is equivalent to you're appending of a pickled or JSON object.

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    objects.append(f.read())
```

If you want each line separately

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        objects.append(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks Cricket,  Since I have three files and they are in three different format, what will be a simple way to combine them together?

Comment: Lists can hold any type of object. I'm not sure I understand the question, but I would personally try to use a custom class rather than a plain list